# How can I choose Ubuntu on my window 8.1 dual boot computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed successfully Ubuntu 14.10 on my window 8.1 as dual boot but I can't choose which OS will boot at the startup. Now I have to go to boot option and need to choose the partition, Ubuntu to boot. I wish not to go to boot option and want to choose which OS will boot.

Comment: you have grub bootloader???

Comment: No sir. What is that? because I am just a new guy to computer.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on a separate HDD or are Windows and Ubuntu installed on the same HDD.

Comment: I divided my 1 TB hard drive into three partitions, C, D and E. I installed it on E sir, window is on C.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install **Grub Customizer** then just go to general settings and pick the entry posistion or just click previously booted. Then go to File-->Save then File--> Install to MBR.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

[image]

Comment: GRUB does not make change. I can't choose OS. Now Window 8.1 always boot first.I made all the steps above u answered.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and type `gedit /etc/default/grub`
you will see `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` just replace 0 with the no of index you want to boot. Index start from `0`

 FOr Example: if you have boot menu like this
windows 8.1
ubuntu 14.04
mac osx

so here windows is at index `0` ubuntu 14.04 at index `1` , mac at index `2`
so if you want to choose to boot to `ubuntu 14.04` directly. you need to change GRUB_DEFAULT=0`from`GRUB_DEFAULT=1`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [Boot-Repair-Disk] You can download your version (32bit) or (64bit) at [sourceforge.net] it is totally FREE, I have used it quite a few times on different machines and it worked GREAT.  Step 1, Download your version and burn it to cd/dvd, Step 2, shutdown system and restart, booting into your CD/DVD Drive [Boot-Repair-Disk], allow software to boot to the boot repair screen and click on the [recommended repair box], and let software do its MAGIC, so you don't have to use command line in a terminal which can be very confusing to some people. Step 3, Shut down and restart system normally and you should have a GRUB screen appear that will be showing all your different operating systems, using arrow keys, move to OS that you would like to use and hit ENTER, it will take you to the OS that you have picked. Be AWARE that you have only about 15 to 20 seconds to chose or it will automaticly take you to the first OS from the top, if this happens just restart and choose again. I can't for the life of me tell you how many times I have gotten sidetracked and had to restart:-(, because I was not paying attention:-)(-: Until you get used to it I would recommend as soon as the screen appears click your down arrow key one time and it will put the GRUB screen on hold and let you get a chance to see the different things you have to chose from. I personally run 2 hard drives on a Gateway 4860 desktop system with 5 different operating systems,including Windows 7. So every time you add a new OS, just run [Boot-Repair-Disk] and it will put everything in a neat little package for you:-) Best repair tool I ever used and it's FREE:-) Have a wonderful day and don't give up!!